# Menu mobile not work in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with menu mobile in internet explorer it does not work - 
I still have a menu from desktop viev. In chrome, firefox, opera is good. Where is the mistake and can i fix it?

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
   if (x.className === "topnav") {
       x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
       x.className = "topnav";
   }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:579px) {
  ul.topnav li {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:579px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
  }
}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
   <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a class="active" data-scroll-nav='1'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll-nav='2'>text1</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll-nav='3'>text2</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll-nav='4'>text3</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll-nav='5'>tex4</a></li>
      <li class="icon">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What version of IE? Any error in console? Can you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Windows IE 11 and mobile i dont see version but phone have windows 8.1. In console i dont see any error.

Comment: Sadly we're not able to provide much help without being able to run it ourselves, but it looks like the code is okay, IE supports the javascript you're using, so I'd try making sure the element is "clickable", as in, make it big or make sure there's nothing overlapping it and that it still fires the event. You should also make sure the function is even running by adding some alert or some way of making sure it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your site I strongly believe you have some parsing errors. Some browsers will ignore them and properly work-around your bugs, which is why it works on Chrome for example, but IE is a little bit more picky on that.

Specifically, you have quite a few brackets that are not properly closed. You can use a service like http://csslint.net/ to properly identify the breaklines.

There's nothing else wrong with the CSS as the bug is that the `.icon` never appears due to that portion of CSS (the media query that sets it as `display: inline-block`) not being interpreted in IE so it still reads `display: none;`.